# What is the expected number of flips you need to get k changeovers?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Flip a fair coin several times. Say that a changeover occurs whenever an outcome differs from the one preceding it. For instance, if you flip the coin 5 times and the outcome is HHTHT, then there are 3 changeovers.

1. Consider n independent flips of this coin, what is the expected number of changeovers?
2. What is the expected number of flips you need to get k changeovers?

**My Attempt**

1. This one isn't too hard. Let $I_j$ be an indicator random variable that equals $1$ if we have a changeover and $0$ otherwise. For $I_j=1$, we need to have a heads on the $j^{th}$ flip and tails on the $(j+1)^{th}$ flip or tails first then heads for $j\in[1,n-1]$. Thus,
   $$\mathbb{P}(I_j=1)=2p(1-p)$$
   Our coin is fair, so $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $\mathbb{P}(I_j=1)=\frac{1}{2}$
   If X is a random variable representing the number of changeovers. Then by linearity of the expectation, we have that
   $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_j\mathbb{P}(I_j)=(n-1)\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{n-1}{2}$$
2. For this part, I am not so sure how to start. Would I use a binomial distribution? As in $X\sim\text{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{2})$ so that our probability is
   $$\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^k(1-\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}$$
   I'm not too sure that this is the right approach or how to continue.

**Edit**

Second attempt for the second part: (I know this is wrong from the comments below, but can I get pointers on where I went wrong?)

Let X be the number of flips before k changeovers. Then $X\sim\text{Geom}(p)$. The probability is given by the formula
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$$
We know that $p=\frac{1}{2}$ from the last part, so $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\frac{1}{2^k}$ The expectation of a geometric distribution is $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p}$, so we have $E[X]=2^k$

Comment: It should simply be $2k+1$ based on the result of the first.

Comment: @MathLover I realize that now, but I am not allowed to use the stopping theorem for this one. I have to model it again

Comment: On at least one answer, you have stated that there are things that you cannot use. These things should be stated in the question so that people don't waste time giving answers, that are valid answers, only to be told that you cannot use the answer on your homework. This is not a site to have your homework done for you. Try to understand the answer and learn that which you don't know.

Comment: I know this site isn't for doing my homework for me and one of the answers below already gave me an answer that I could copy down if I wanted to but I still wanted to understand more about how to approach this problem if I wasn't told to do the first part. That's why I made the edit using the formulas I was taught to learn where I went wrong.

Comment: It is evident from your question that you have tried and are not trying to get your homework done for you. I am just mentioning the impact that such a comment can have. However, if there are restrictions to what you can use, then those should be stated in the question. For example, I would use $S$ for a flip that has no predecessor or does not differ from its predecessor ($S$ for "same"), and $D$ for a flip that differs from its predecessor ($D$ for "different"). You will always start with an $S$ and then after that, $\frac12$ are $S$ and $\frac12$ are $D$. Count the number of $D$'s.

Comment: Does that use the "stopping theorem"? (I am not sure exactly what that is).

Comment: Yeah, I should have been clear about what I could and couldn't use in my question. I'm not too sure what stopping theorem is either but my professor told me that I can't just solve for n using the result from the first part because he hasn't taught stopping theorem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution for the first part is correct.

For the second part, let the probability of heads be $p$ and the probability of tails be $q=1-p$.  If we've just thrown heads, then the number of tosses until the next tails is geometrically distributed with parameter $q$ and the expected number of tosses is $\frac1q$.  Similarly the expected number of tosses until the first heads after a tails is $\frac1p$.  If the first toss is heads then the expected number of tosses until the $k$th changeover is $$1+\left\lceil\frac k2\right\rceil\frac1q+\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor\frac1p,$$
since $\left\lceil\frac k2\right\rceil$ changeovers are from heads to tails, and $\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor$ changeovers are from tails to heads.  This is because the first changeover is from heads to tails, and the types of the changeovers alternate.

Similarly, if the first toss is tails then the expected number of tosses until the $k$th changeover is $$1+\left\lceil\frac k2\right\rceil\frac1p+\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor\frac1q.$$ Weighting these by the appropriate probabilities, we get that the expectation is $$1+2\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor+\left\lceil\frac k2\right\rceil\left(\frac pq+\frac qp\right).$$
With a fair coin $p=q$, and this simplifies to $2k+1$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the expression $1+[\frac{k}{2}]\frac{1}{q}+[\frac{k}{2}]\frac{1}{p}$? I understood how you got the expectations $\frac{1}{p}\text{ and }\frac{1}{q}$ but not how you put it together

Comment: @James Anderson I added some more details.

Answer (score 4):

**1** More simply, we aren't concerned as to which face appeared on the first flip, or later on, on the $(i-1)^{th}$ flip.

With $X_i$ as the indicator variable indicating an $i_{th}$ flip changeover,

$\Bbb E[X_i] = \Bbb P[X_i] = \frac1 2$

and by linearity of expectation, summing from $i=2\,to\;  n, \,\Bbb E[X] = \frac{(n-1)}2$

**2** From results of part $1, k = \frac{(n-1)}2$,

so $n = 2k+1$